# Single instance of component react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to make a component where it renders a modal.
This component should have `states{Key(integer),ImageLink(string),Visible(bool)}`.
I am using `flatlist`. I want to render the component's modal on flatlist parent but component. States changes upon touch on flatlist child.

**For example:**

***Modal Component which means to be single instance***

```
import React from "react";
import {
    View,
    Modal,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    Platform
} from "react-native";

export default class MySingleInstanceModal extend Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Visiable: props.Visiable, \\Bool For turning Modal On or Off
            ImageLink: props.ImageLink, \\String Image Online Link
            Key: props.PostKey,\\integer Key
        };
    }

    NextImage = (Current,Link )=> {
        this.setState({ ImageLink: Link,Key:Current+1 });
    };

    ToggleMeOff = () => {
        this.setState({ TurnMeOn: false });
    };

    ToggleMeOn = (MyKey,MyLink) => {
        this.setState({ TurnMeOn: true,ImageLink: MyLink,Key:MyKey  });
    };

    PrevImage = (Current,Link )=> {
        this.setState({ ImageLink: Link,Key:Current-1 });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Modal
                    animationType="slide"
                    transparent={false}
                    visible={this.state.TurnMeOn}
                >
                    <View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>
                        <View>
                            <Text>Hello World!</Text>
                            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.ToggleMeOff}>
                                <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                            <Image
                                source={{ uri: this.state.ImageLink }}
                                resizeMethod={"resize"}/>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Calling In Flatlist Parent:**

```
render() {
    return  (
      <View style={Style1.container}>
      <MySingleInstanceModal/> // Here I want to call render
      <FlatList
              data={data}
              initialNumToRender={4}
              keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
              renderItem={this._renderItem}
              onEndReached={this._reachedEnd}
              refreshing={isRefreshing}
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
              onRefresh={this._refreshdata}
              ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            />
    </view>)
}
```

***And want to change `states` of `MySingleInstanceModal` in `flatlist items`(`flatlist child`)***

**somewhere in the rendering of flatlist child item**

```
render(){
    return  (
        ...
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => 
            MySingleInstanceModal.ToggleMeOn(this.state.Link,this.state.Key)}>
            <Text>Open Modal For Me</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        ...
    )
}
```

Which means component will render at parent but its states will be controlled by the child(Every flatlist item)

Comment: `ToggleMeOn` is a class method so it is not accessible as a static function. Also if you will turn it into a static one you will not be able to access the component state! you probably should get a reference of your modal component or use a global store like `redux` or `mobx`.

Comment: @Coyote
 Yes ,I know about static and i also know that i will not able to do that. But its only for concept of what i want.
OK,so how to do with redux or mobx.

Comment: using redux or mobx you will get a global store so changing it from anywhere will trigger update event to all subscribed components so instead of toggleMeOn or toggleMeOff you will just update the store and the modal will get its new state from the store.